# How to change filter's CSS in Spotfire without having a visible text area?

Tags: css, spotfire

I want to change CSS of one of the filters in Spotfire.

One way of doing it is to add a text area, duplicate the filter there and add CSS.

For example:

```
<head>
<style>
.ColumnFilter .sf-element-filter-item:nth-of-type(2) {background-color: salmon;}
</style>
</head>

<SpotfireControl id="42" />
```

This changes the filter's background color both in the text area and in the filter panel.

Now the problem is that I don't want to have the text area, only the panel. But if I remove the text area, the CSS effect in the panel disappears.

Comment: just to clarify, you want to change the styling of a filter that is rendered in the Filters panel?

Answer (score 1):

Store your css inside a document property or javascript, and use js to append it to the head. It still requires the use of a text area, but only needs to initialize once (ie. start page, landing page, home page, etc.). When reloading your browser, just remember to go back to that same page so that the js can re-initialize.

```
$(function(){
    cssTxt = $("#css").text();  //label property 

    if($('#custom-css').length){
        //do nothing
        console.log('custom-css has already been appended') 
    } else {
        //add css to head
        console.log('%cappending custom-css','color:red') 

        $('head').append($('<style id=custom-css>'+cssTxt +'</style>'));
    }
});
```

Jolene Robertson